# Worst case for power consumption of bluetooth module

Tags: current, circuit-design, bluetooth

I wish to figure out the conditions under which this device will be consuming most current - [NRF52832](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nRF52832_PS_v1.4.pdf)

The supply voltage is fixed at 3.3 V and the schematic is exactly the same as the one recommended in the datasheet:

[image]

The antenna is a copper track antenna (not sure how relevant).

I looked at the datasheet, under section 17, they seem to give values for some operating cases:
[image]

But these values seem too low to be worst case. I have never worked with bluetooth modules, for cellular I know that the consumption will increase when the signal is weak; that they have really high peak currents; Is this also the case for bluetooth?

Comment: BLE has a maximum transmission power of 10mW for most versions, so 21mW to transmit 10mW of power doesn't seem unreasonable. Its a low range, energy efficient protocol. Unlike cellular which orders of magnitudes more transmission power to reach orders of magnitudes longer range.

Comment: However, that assumes your application is using Bluetooth low energy, and not Bluetooth. If you are using Bluetooth, thats the wrong table.

Comment: Yeah, BLE is right. Also, the only tables i found are for BLE and ultra-low power, does that mean that the chip does not support standard Bluetooth? Thanks for confirming that the power range is reasonable, on that note, are there really no practical current peaks present during certain operating conditions? Intuition tells me that there should be a scenario in which the current might reach, say 5x the amount of its average value.

Answer (score 2):

1. BLE radios do not automatically increase their transmit power when the signal is weak, as some cellular radios do.
2. The table you attached shows current consumption for 0 dBm transmit. This is the default transmit power, but you can increase it in your firmware to  +4 dBm. That will draw more than twice the current listed for 0 dBm.
3. In BLE, the duty cycle for transmitting is usually very short, so the average current consumption may be far less than these figures. If you are using a small coin cell for power, you can reduce the  peak current demands on the battery with a bulk capacitor on the Vcc line. I use 10 to 50 uF.
4. Note that the radio is not the only current-consumer on the module. The CPU can draw 3 to 8 mA as well, so even when the radio is off there will be current draw if you haven't allowed the CPU to sleep.

Comment: "I use 10 to 50 uF." But be aware that large caps like that can have significant leakage currents in the µA range. If the system spends a lot of time in deep sleep, this will significantly reduce battery life.